# Why do li items default to a newline?

Tags: css, html-lists

Basic CSS question. Why do **li** items, by default, end up on new lines?

```
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
</ul>
```

Block elements end up on new lines but it isn't in MDN's list of [block elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Block-level_elements). Instead, [they are list-items](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/li.html#li-display) and their default CSS is something like:

```
li {
  display: list-item;
  text-align: -webkit-match-parent; }
```

I'm just seeing if there's a general understanding that will explain this or if I have to learn that lists are a special case.

Rich

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [CSS1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS1/#list-item-elements) for list-item elements says:

> Elements with a 'display' property value of 'list-item' are formatted as block-level elements, but preceded by a list-item marker. The type of marker is determined by the 'list-style' property. The marker is placed according to the value of the 'list-style' property:

However, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) describe their implementation of the spec in the following way, stating that the list-item display value:

> ...generates a block box for the content and a separate list-item inline box.

Either way, `display:list-item` will generate a block level element which forces itself to be drawn on a new line by essentially adding a line-break before and after its content.

Comment: So, the ul is a block and it uses up the width. It puts it's items in an inline box and by default these end up on a new line (odd given the name inline?). I'm trying to learn if there's a general rule but it sounds like I have to just know that lists put items on a new line by default?

Comment: All list types (`ul`, `ol` and `dl`) are all [block-level elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Block-level_elements). `li` elements can be thought of as block-level too, just with a preceding marker added on.

Comment: OK, I'll buy that :-) although it's not a standard block element (and missing from the block element list) it is, in respect to formatting, a block element. Thanks Ian.

Comment: Any time @Rich it was a good question, and I agree with you in that it's not all that clear. MDN and W3C materials are always the goto resources for accurate information :)

Answer (score 0):

The li element relates to the block element. Block elements always take the full line. Remember h1,h2,h3,h4,div elements, ect. These elements have the same property too. As you already noticed these elements can be put in line using display inline-block.

Comment: By relates you mean it's parent is the ul? li is not a block element - apparently an inline box. I would have imagined it just would be like text and just fill up the width until it hit the bounds of the box and then go onto the next line. Obviously, this is not the case :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are positioned as a new line each `li` tag by default, as it is the "list" tag.